# window.location.href как задать жесткий фильтр соответствия названия?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть несколько названий страниц c похожими названиями:
-/teacher
-/teachercontest
-/videoteacher

Условие if(window.location.href.indexOf("teacher") > -1) срабатывает для всех из них. Нужно чтобы условие срабатывало только для /teacher, а для остальных нет. Как это отфильтровать?

Comment: а если 4 или нет

Answer (score 1):

```
const re = /^\/teacher(?:[/?.]|$)/i; 
if (re.test(window.location.pathname)) {
  /* ... */
}
```

Свойство `location.href`, помимо пути документа, содержит также схему (протокол), и доменное имя.
Поэтому, лучше проверять свойство `pathname`.

---

```js
const fakeLocations = [
  { pathname: '/teacher' }, 
  { pathname: '/teachercontest' }, 
  { pathname: '/videoteacher' }, 
  { pathname: '/about/teacher' }, 
  { pathname: '/teachers' }, 
  { pathname: '/teacher?foo=bar' }, 
  { pathname: '/teacher/' }, 
  { pathname: '/teacher.php' }
]; 

const results = fakeLocations.map(
  ({ pathname: p }) => [
    p.padEnd(18, ' '), 
    /^\/teacher(?:[/?.]|$)/i.test(p)
  ].join('➝  ')
); 

document.body.textContent = results.join('\n');
```

```css
body { font: 16px monospace; white-space: pre; }
```

Comment: В значении `pathname` не может быть *query* (типа `/teacher?foo=bar`), это лишнее... так что можно смело убрать из регулярки символ `?`. В ответе оставлю, может это кому-нибудь пригодится в качестве примера/подсказки.

Answer (score 0):

```
function isTeacher() {
  let location = window.location.href.split('/');
  return location.filter(v => v.toLowerCase() === 'teacher').length !== 1 ? false : true;
}
```

ну или последний элемент что бы был равен teacher тогда тоже выполняется услвоие

Comment: тогда уж используйте метод `some`. Зачем весь массив перебирать